# Pattern matching in a let expression

Tags: haskell, syntax

How do you extract a value from a variable of an unknown constructor?

For instance, I would like to negate the value in an Either if was constructed as a Right:

```
let Right x = getValue
in Right (negate x)
```

This code successfully binds Right's value (an Int in this case) to x.

This works, but what if getValue returns a Left instead?  Is there a way to determine the type of a variable in a let expression?  Or is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In general, what you can do is this:

```
case getValue of
  Right x -> Right $ negate x
  e       -> e
```

What this does should be clear: it's just like pattern matching in a function argument, but against a value.  To do what you need, you have a default case which catches anything not matched, and then return that.

In your particular case, however, you can do something slightly nicer:

```
negate `fmap` getValue
```

Or, with `import Control.Applicative`, you can use `<$>` as a synonym for `fmap` (`negate <$> getValue`).  The `fmap` function has type `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`.  For any functor<sup>1</sup>, `fmap` converts a function on ordinary values to a function within the functor.  For instance, lists are a functor, and for lists, `fmap = map`.  Here, `Either e` represents a functor which is either an exception `Left e` or a value `Right a`; applying a function to a `Left` does nothing, but applying a function to a `Right` applies it within the `Right`.  In other words,

```
instance Functor (Either e) where
  fmap _ (Left l)  = Left l
  fmap f (Right r) = Right $ f r
```

Thus the `case` version is the direct answer to your question, but your particular example is more nicely approximated by `fmap`.

**1:**  To a first approximation, functors are "containers".  If you're not comfortable with the various type classes, I recommed [the Typeclassopedia](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia) for a comprehensive reference; there are many more tutorials out there, and the best way to get a feel for them is to just play with them.  However, the `fmap` for specific types is often readily usable (especially, in my opinion, when written `<$>`).

Comment: And don't forget nice `either Left (Right . negate) getValue` from `Data.Either` ;)

Comment: Thanks.  The case expression is what I was looking for.  I don't understand the rest of your answer; I will come back to it once I've learned more.

Comment: @ony: I think you should write your comment up as a seperate answer, it is really the intermediate level solution between the `case` and the `fmap`!

Comment: @yatima2975: I guess question is more general - pattern matching. `fmap` and `either` is just for particular example (where type `Either` is used).

Answer (score 2):

Answer to the title of this question:
I don't see big difference between "`... where`" and "`let ... in ...`". Both allows you do declare several cases of function argument bindings:

```
f val = let negR (Right x) = Right (negate x)
            negR y = y
        in negR val
```

or
`let { negR (Right x) = Right (negate x); negR y = y; } in negR val`